# Manually draw log-spaced tick marks and labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I frequently find myself working in log units for my plots, for example taking `np.log10(x)` of data before binning it or creating contour plots. The problem is, when I then want to make the plots presentable, the axes are in ugly log units, and the tick marks are evenly spaced.

If I let matplotlib do all the conversions, i.e. by setting `ax.set_xaxis('log')` then I get very nice looking axes, however I can't do that to my data since it is e.g. already binned in log units. I could manually change the tick labels, but that wouldn't make the tick spacing logarithmic. I suppose I could also go and manually specify the position of every minor tick such it had log spacing, but is that the only way to achieve this? That is a bit tedious so it would be nice if there is a better way.

For concreteness, here is a plot:
[image]

I want to have the tick labels as `10^x` and `10^y` (so '1' is '10', 2 is '100' etc.), and I want the minor ticks to be drawn as `ax.set_xaxis('log')` would draw them.

Edit: For further concreteness, suppose the plot is generated from an image, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.misc
img = scipy.misc.face()

x_range = [-5,3] # log10 units
y_range = [-55, -45] # log10 units

p = plt.imshow(img,extent=x_range+y_range)

plt.show()
```

and all we want to do is change the axes appearance as I have described.

Edit 2: Ok, ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer is very clever but it is a bit more specific to images than I wanted. I have another example, of binned data this time. Perhaps their technique still works on this, though it is not clear to me if that is the case.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datashader as ds
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as sps

v1 = sps.lognorm(loc=0, scale=3, s=0.8)
v2 = sps.lognorm(loc=0, scale=1, s=0.8)
x = np.log10(v1.rvs(100000))
y = np.log10(v2.rvs(100000))
x_range=[np.min(x),np.max(x)]
y_range=[np.min(y),np.max(y)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"x": x, "y": y})

#------ Aggregate the data ------
cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=30, plot_height=30, x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range)
agg = cvs.points(df, 'x', 'y')

# Create contour plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.contourf(agg, extent=x_range+y_range)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is rather unclear. Why do take the log of the data in the first place? Leave that out and use `ax.set_xaxis('log')` and you get the desired plot as far as I understand.

Comment: Because, for example, I have already drawn the plot using other tools in log units. In this particular case I have what is basically an image coming from datashader, and I need to draw the axes nicely in matplotlib. Perhaps a good trick would be to take the non-logged data extents and get matplotlib to draw empty axes with `set_xaxis('log')`, and then add the image into that, or something.

Comment: Would you mind just creating a [mcve] of the issue? Otherwise this is all guessing here.

Comment: Ok, I have added one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer to this question is probably given in this post:

[Can I mimic a log scale of an axis in matplotlib without transforming the associated data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811628/can-i-mimic-a-log-scale-of-an-axis-in-matplotlib-without-transforming-the-associ)

However here an easy option might be to scale the content of the axes and then set the axes to a log scale.

#### A. image

You may plot your image on a logarithmic scale but make all pixels the same size in log units. Unfortunately `imshow` does not allow for such kind of image ([any more](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.0.0.html#non-linear-scales-on-image-plots)), but one may use `pcolormesh` for that purpose.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.misc
img = scipy.misc.face()

extx = [-5,3]     # log10 units
exty = [-45, -55] # log10 units
x = np.logspace(extx[0],extx[-1],img.shape[1]+1)
y = np.logspace(exty[0],exty[-1],img.shape[0]+1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

c =  img.reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1],img.shape[2]))/255.0
m = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,X[:-1,:-1], color=c, linewidth=0)
m.set_array(None)

plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.gca().set_yscale("log")

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### B. contour

The same concept can be used for a contour plot.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.1,1.9)
y = np.linspace(-1.4,1.55)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
agg = np.exp(-(X**2+Y**2)*2)


fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.gca().set_yscale("log")


exp = lambda x: 10.**(np.array(x))

cf = ax.contourf(exp(X), exp(Y),agg, extent=exp([x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()]))

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm ok that is cool but a bit more specific to the image case than I wanted. I added another example, of data binned with something aside from numpy.histogram (i.e. where you cannot just give log bin edges to it), and then making a contour plot of the result. Can something like you suggest still work there?

Comment: Haha, sure and once I solved that case for you you will decide that you'll need still something different.

Comment: Well I was hoping for a general purpose solution to the problem of changing axes to nice log units, not something fine-tuned to this or that type of plot.

Comment: Anyways, I updated the answer with a solution for a contour. I'm curious what comes next. ;-)

Comment: I actually forgot that I had answered a similar question already. This could be what you understand by general purpose solution (although it is also cumbersome to implement); I updated the answer.

Comment: Ahh, excellent, yes between the two examples and your other answer that just changes the axes this deals with everything. Thanks a lot, I have accepted the answer. It is a shame that matplotlib doesn't have something built in to just automatically deal with this, since this is an extremely common occurrence with scientific data (i.e. the data being directly recorded, manipulated, etc. in log units), and it is a pain to have to manually transform the data back and forth, or mess with the axis details like you show. I might try and make some nice wrapper function to automatically do all this.

Comment: Even though this is a good answer to the question, I was still hoping for something more robust... Maybe there should still be a question open?

Comment: Both questions are open and can be answered. Everyone is free to provide a different solution, although it's not too clear to me what more you are expecting.