# Different Spacing for same axes in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a graph using pyplot with different spacing for different intervals. 
 
I want to zoom in specific parts of the interval without another floating box. For example: Consider the graph and scaling as below:

```
  |
30-
  |
20-           - - - - 
  |          /
10-         /
  |        /
 2-       / 
  |      / 
 1-     /
  |- - -
0-,__,__,___,___,___,
  0  1  2   20  30  40
```

I have tried looking up online but I am unable to find the resource. 
It will be really great if someone can help me.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a [broken axis example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32186074/8881141)

Comment: In addition you may scale the data as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811628/can-i-mimic-a-log-scale-of-an-axis-in-matplotlib-without-transforming-the-associ) or
use a custom scale as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306099/how-to-put-different-in-magnitude-values-at-same-distance-on-x-axis)
or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463431/custom-logarithmic-axis-scaling-in-matplotlib).

Comment: I closed as duplicate. A useful question should mention in how far existing answers do not help. See [ask] and [mcve].